# Java finding amount of times number comes up

Tags: arrays

I need to write a program to find if a number appears in an array of 50 numbers more than once.

I have the array generating 50 random numbers but cant seem to get my head round writing the loop to get it to see how many are the same..

Comment: welcome to SO, what have you tried so far ??

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: whatever you have tried paste here

Comment: @Christine update the code in your question itself, not in the comments :)

Comment: use map, where key is rolled number and value is number of times it appeared

Comment: I would not use an array, but an ArrayList like that you can use the contains() method. Saves you on for loop.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object), i can post you some code when i get home, i actually did write this once...cu in 2 hours

Comment: the last sample shows how to do it with nested loop

Comment: this should not be a problem for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Following code will count each rolled number and store count in `numbers` map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    Integer num = die.roll();
    Integer count = numbers.get(num);
    if (count == null) {
        count = Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
    count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1);
    numbers.put(num, count);
}
```

Then you can check all map entries and find those that rolled more than once.

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : numbers.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().intValue() > 1) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " rolled more than once");
    }
}
```

Or you can just change condition in first loop to output numbers there:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    Integer num = die.roll();
    Integer count = numbers.get(num);
    if (count != null) {
        System.out.println(num + " rolled more than once");
    } else {
        numbers.put(num, Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
}
```

And finally you can still use arrays to find number in it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    nums[i] = die.roll();
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (nums[i] == nums[j]) {
            System.out.println(nums[i] + " rolled more than once");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try sorting the data

```
int[] nums = new int[50];
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] = die.roll();
java.util.Arrays.sort(nums);
int dupes = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
    if(nums[i] == nums[i+1) dupes++;
}
```

Sorting the data puts all equal elements next to eachother, so you can find them with one pass. Of course, you have to sort it, which is not a one pass operation.

This eliminates the overhead of using a map and is still very fast. The sort is `n lg n`, which is slower than the `n` solution of using a map, but with such a small `n` the overhead of the map might be significant. The code itself is also very simple to follow.

See this self contained example that uses numbers 0-19 in a 10 element array (scaled down the numbers for easy review; the concept applies entirely.)

```
import java.util.*;
class Christine {
    static Random random = new Random();
    static int dieroll() {
        return random.nextInt(20);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] = dieroll();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int dupes = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            if(nums[i] == nums[i+1]) dupes++;
        }
        System.out.println(dupes);
    }


}
```

You run the example like so:

```
c:\files\j>javac Christine.java

c:\files\j>java Christine
[2, 9, 8, 5, 11, 12, 15, 15, 16, 7]
1

c:\files\j>java Christine
[10, 10, 1, 18, 11, 6, 4, 3, 9, 5]
1

c:\files\j>java Christine
[8, 0, 13, 4, 5, 4, 16, 13, 6, 18]
2
```

In the first run, there are two 15's. In the second, there are two 10s. In the third, there are two 13s and two 4s.

Consider this example:

```
c:\files\j>java Christine
[17, 19, 19, 3, 19, 4, 18, 19, 1, 1]
4
```

This counts 3 dupes for the 4 different 19s, and a dupe for the two 1s. Now why is there 3 dupes for the 19s? Because if we call the 19s a, b, c, and d, a sees b as a dupe, b sees c as a dupe, and c sees d as a dupe. So there's three. You'd have to add additional logic to make it more robust to catch all 6 dupes for that.

Comment: Your code will produce IndexOutOfBoundsException, oops. ignore it - i am blind

Comment: @Christine It does work. I've made a self contained example that illustrates that it does indeed work, which I'm about to edit in.